# How can I send some HTML, render a view, then send more HTML in Express+Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, view, express

I'm using Node.js+Express, and I've come across a case where I need to send some HTML, render a view, then send some more HTML in the one response.

The flow would be:

```
res.send('some html');
res.render('module.html', {});
res.send('more html');
```

Now I know that `res.render` supports a callback, so I could do:

```
res.render('module.html', {}, function () {
    res.send('more html');
});
```

But `res.send()` doesn't appear to. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend injecting a rendered partial view into your html and sending that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like Raynos Said I would recommend looking into [view partials](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials). [This video](http://www.screenr.com/4AL) from Author TJ explains the basics.

As a sidenote `res.send` send a full response and then closes the connection. You can not be using that if you want to send more text after that.[image]

---

So you have to use node.js native [res.write](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/http.html#response.write) to do what you want instead.

Comment: Thanks Alfred, I don't know why I didn't think to use res.write instead. Make sense.

I didn't want to use partials particularly as it is literally two additional tags I want to wrap the view around. I thought it might be a bit overkill for partials.